# Получить ответ с помощью c# от сервера

Tags: php, c#

Есть сервер написанный на php.

```
<?php
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost" и тд);
  $login=$_GET["login"];
  $pass=$_GET["pass"];

  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE login= '$login'");
  $query=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if ($pass== $query['password']) {
      //Здесь я хочу что бы при успешной авторизации сервер вернул что авторизация прошла успешно.
```

Сам клиент написан на c#.
Хелп:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE login= '$login'");
$query=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
if ($pass== $query['password']) {
    echo "авторизация прошла успешно";
}
```

Comment: А если я захочу вернуть из базы данных список друзей пользователя(имена и тд), то как?

Comment: То надо прочесть учебник по пхп или хотя бы документацию по функции mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: @Julianoo, формируете сообщение заданного формата обмена данных, к примеру CSV, JSON или XML и читаете его в клиенте как сообщение данного формата. О тонкостях самого кода учебник и интернет.

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста)

Comment: `'$login'"`, Вы серьёзно?

Comment: Нет, это шутка.

Comment: @Ипатьев: Вы так не шутите.